# SOME OF THE PRODUCTS BELOW DO NOT HAVE ALL THE REQUIRED OPTIONS

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, bundled-product

I have created a bundled product with two product options but both the options are required. When I try to order such a product it redirects me to checkout page showing an error to specify options. But since both the product option is set to required there is nothing to select.
I tried to save the product from Magento Admin and when it gets saved from backed the problem is solved. But I want the product to be created programmatically. [image]

[image]